# Change JPanel at runtime with a button

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jpanel, jbutton

Hello I have a main layout made in this way:

---

```
            |         |
Main pane   |Menu pane|
            |         |
```

Now, menu pane is made just of button: clicking on a button switches main panel with another panel.
On click event is made this way:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
     mainPanel = new MyNewPanel();
     this.revalidate();
}
```

But, for some reason, main panel does not change!

Comment: If `Menu pane` is not a menu (e.g. `JMenu`) then it should not be called a 'menu'.  It would probably best be called a 'tool bar' & changed to a `JToolBar`.  Also be sure to add a question in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not setting the main component of your container. You need to add your new panel and call `validate()` on that container.

Note, depending on your the layout of your container you may need to remove the currently visible component first.

[CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) could manage all this for you.

Comment: +1 for `CardLayout`. But don't forget, depending on the layout, you may need to remove the previous panel